# Node.js and io.js installation in windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is what i have done,
in my fresh laptop, with windows 8.1, i have installed both Node.js 0.12.7 and io.js 2.3.4.
[image: Installed Control Panel]

While trying to check the npm,node,iojs version by opening command prompt,
This is what i got,
[image: See the version's of node,iojs,npm]

As per this blog of nodejs
http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/07/09/node-v0-12-7-stable/

Npm version 2.11.3

& see the node version which shows 2.3.4 ?

Why is it showing like this?
This same installation works on my PC, with same configuration.

What is the best way of using both in windows?

Eventhough i differentiate iojs and nodejs which npm version will command prompt will invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing iojs installs a node.exe which is the same as iojs.exe

just remove node.exe from the iojs install directory

npm will be the one from iojs in your case - I think - check the PATH variable, if iojs path comes before nodejs path, then it will be npm from iojs, otherwise npm from nodejs

Why would you want to install both anyway?

Comment: In My Day Job is use Node.js (ES5) , but for knowledge gaining purpose is  will use io.js (ES6). :). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think which npm is used will be of much significance - but, I can't be sure of that